# Capturing traffic in the server using Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am using `Servlet` to see the traffic on the server when I deploy the app. If there is any traffic on the server before even the app is deployed I return `false` otherwise `true`. So far it is working fine, but I read about preprocessing  Servlet filter. Is there a way to the same thing as a pre process using servlet filter?

Java class:

```
public class RESTActivityServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4971654546064688463L;

private Long countServerTraffic;
public static final String REQUEST_COUNT_1H = "RequestCount_1h";
public static final String REQUEST_COUNT_15M = "RequestCount_15m";
public static final String REQUEST_COUNT_1M = "RequestCount_1m";
public static final String REQUEST_COUNT_15S = "RequestCount_15s";
public static final String REQUEST_COUNT_1S = "RequestCount_1s";    
public static final String ACTIVITY_JSP_INTERVAL = "interval";

public void init( ServletConfig config ) throws ServletException {
    countServerTraffic = 0L;
}

public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
    long defaultTime = 60;
    if( request.getParameter( ACTIVITY_JSP_INTERVAL ) != null ) {
        defaultTime = Long.valueOf( request.getParameter( ACTIVITY_JSP_INTERVAL ) );
    }
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType( "text/plain" );
    response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" );
    response.setHeader( "Pragma", "No-Cache" );
    out.print( hasServerHadTrafficInLastTimePeriod( defaultTime ) );
    countServerTraffic++;
}

public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet( request, response );
}

public Boolean hasServerHadTrafficInLastTimePeriod( long time ) {
    try {
        String[] attrs = null;

        if( time > 0 && time <=1 ) {
            attrs = new String[] { REQUEST_COUNT_1S };
        } else if( time > 1 && time <= 15 ) {
            attrs = new String[] { REQUEST_COUNT_1S, REQUEST_COUNT_15S };
        } else if( time > 15 && time <= 60 ) {
            attrs = new String[] { REQUEST_COUNT_1S, REQUEST_COUNT_15S, REQUEST_COUNT_1M };
        } else if( time > 60 && time <= 900 ) {
            attrs = new String[] { REQUEST_COUNT_1S, REQUEST_COUNT_15S, REQUEST_COUNT_1M, REQUEST_COUNT_15M };
        } else if( time > 900 && time <= 3600 ) {
            attrs = new String[] { REQUEST_COUNT_1S, REQUEST_COUNT_15S, REQUEST_COUNT_1M, REQUEST_COUNT_15M, REQUEST_COUNT_1H };
        } else {
            attrs = new String[] { "RequestCount_total" };
        }

        for( String attr : attrs ) {
            if( countServerTraffic instanceof Long ) {
                if( ( (Long)countServerTraffic ).longValue() != 0l ) {
                    System.out.println( "Attribute " + attr + " found traffic of " + countServerTraffic );
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println( "Exception in Activity Servlet: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace( ex ) );
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

web.xml:

```
 <servlet> 
    <display-name>ActivityServlet</display-name> 
    <description>ESign Activity</description> 
    <servlet-name>ActivityServlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.activity.RESTActivityServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>appName</param-name> 
        <param-value>ESignatureUIWAR</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>ActivityServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Activity</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the Servlet Filters. It should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: In a word, yes. Too broad.

Answer (score 0):

`Long` is NOT thread safe, so you can't use it as a servlet instance variable for your counter, so you need to use `AtomicLong` (which is thread safe) as shown below:

```
public class RESTActivityServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4971654546064688463L;

    AtomicLong countServerTraffic = new AtomicLong(0);//AtomicLong variable which thread safe

    public static final String REQUEST_COUNT_1H = "RequestCount_1h";
    public static final String REQUEST_COUNT_15M = "RequestCount_15m";
    public static final String REQUEST_COUNT_1M = "RequestCount_1m";
    public static final String REQUEST_COUNT_15S = "RequestCount_15s";
    public static final String REQUEST_COUNT_1S = "RequestCount_1s";    
    public static final String ACTIVITY_JSP_INTERVAL = "interval";

    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {

        countServerTraffic.getAndIncrement();//increment

        long defaultTime = 60;
        if( request.getParameter( ACTIVITY_JSP_INTERVAL ) != null ) {
            defaultTime = Long.valueOf( request.getParameter( ACTIVITY_JSP_INTERVAL ) );
        }
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType( "text/plain" );
        response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" );
        response.setHeader( "Pragma", "No-Cache" );
        out.print( hasServerHadTrafficInLastTimePeriod( defaultTime ) );
    }

    public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )throws ServletException, IOException {
         doGet( request, response );
    }

    public Boolean hasServerHadTrafficInLastTimePeriod( long time ) {
        //add your code
    }
}
```

Comment: This is like a replacement for Long. I am trying to implement a filter as a pre process. To check for any request if exists on the server before the app is deployed.